# Is NOT being a social network a benefit?

Tags: login, registration, landing-page

I'm working on a new website project that requires users to log in to access the content, and once logged in they can publish, share and follow content.

Since logging in is a required action to gain access. I'm using social network buttons to grant new users quick registration.

I started to question if social networks are now a negative impression for new users. Should I clearly state on my landing page that this website is *not* a social network. That there is no way to follow other users, and that this is not a space to share personal information.

The reason I ask is that the user experience of a landing page that only lets you log in tends to be for social networks. Facebook, Google+ and Twitter all have log ins as their main landing page.

Comment: "The reason I ask is that the user experience of a landing page that only lets you log in tends to be for social networks. Facebook, Google+ and Twitter all have log ins as their main landing page." - to my opinion, that is hardly the case. Why would you think so?

Comment: So how exactly is a website that allows you to publish, share and follow content not a social network?

Comment: @Noctiphobia it sounds content-focused rather than user-focused, so not exactly a social network. Social networks connect users to each other, and this one does not.

Comment: @PavelRyzhov I was struggling to clearly define what makes a website a social network. I assumed that if you're not connecting users together to create a network, then it's not a social network. Message forums for example allow people to like, share and post messages. I don't think we would call a forum a social network. If I have a lot of the same features as a social network, but I remove the connection between users (i.e. following, friending) then is it still a social network?

Comment: I can see that this question would be opinion based. Any ideas on how I can update it to be relevant to UX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website will provide social network services (by definition).
The "it is not a social network" statement is misleading.

That "negative impression" comes from the abuse of visitor's information, and misleading/ambiguous company statements about information privacy and security.

A login mechanism made by a major corporation, is actually an information exchange mechanism. It is not for free. You provide them valuable information about your visitors.

In practice:
I would state clearly what i am, not the opposite.

Along with the corporate login mechanisms, I would provide my authentication mechanism 

or just my authentication mechanism, no corporate logins.

Here is a good example for your case: [www.tumblr.com](http://www.tumblr.com)